# singular solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $2y^2dx+(x-y+1)^2dy=0$ I need to find all possible solutions. so
$$
2y^2dx+(x-y+1)^2dy=0 \Longrightarrow y'=\frac{-2y^2}{(x-y+1)^2}
$$
changing variables to $v = x + 1$ and $u = y$
$$
u'=\frac{-2u^2}{(v-1-u+1)^2}=-2\frac{u^2}{(v-u)^2}=-2(\frac{u}{v-u})^2=-2(\frac{1}{(\frac{v-u}{u})})^2 = -2(\frac{1}{\frac{v}{u}-1})^2
$$
changing variables again $z=\frac{u}{v}$
$$
z'v+z=-2(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{z}-1})^2=\frac{-2z^2}{(1-z)^2}\Longrightarrow z'v=\frac{-2z^2-z(1-z)^2}{(1-z)^2}=\frac{-z(1-z^2)}{(1-z)^2}=\frac{-z(1+z)}{(1-z)}
$$
This is a separable equation so the solution is
$$
\int^z{\frac{1-u}{-u(1+u)}du}=\int^v{\frac{1}{t}dt}+C\Longrightarrow 2ln{|z+1|}-ln{|z|}=ln{C|v|}\Longrightarrow \frac{(z+1)^2}{z}=Cv\Longrightarrow (z+1)^2=Cvz
$$

and changing back to original variables I get
$$
(z+1)^2=Cvz \Longrightarrow (\frac{u}{v}+1)^2=Cv\frac{u}{v} \Longrightarrow (\frac{u+v}{v})^2=Cu \Longrightarrow (u+v)^2=Cuv^2 \Longrightarrow (y+x+1)^2=Cy(x+1)^2
$$
during this process I also get 2 singular solutions to $z$: $z=0$ and $z=-1$ going back to $y$ I get $y(x)=0, x\neq -1$ and $y=-x-1$ but when I try to use the second singular solution $y=-x-1$ I get $$y' = \frac{-2(-x-1)^2}{(x-(-x-1+1)^2}=\frac{-2(x+1)^2}{4(x+1)^2} = -\frac{1}{2}\neq -1 = (-x-1)'$$. Did I do something wrong along the way? can it be that the singular solution for z aren't singular for y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{-2z^2-z(1-z)^2}{(1-z)^2}=\frac{-2z^2-z+2z^2-z^3}{(1-z)^2}=\frac{-z(1+z^2)}{(1-z)^2}.$$ However, you wrote $$\frac{-2z^2-z(1-z)^2}{(1-z)^2}=\frac{-z(1-z^2)}{(1-z)^2}.$$ This was your mistake. So you should have $$z'v=\frac{-z(1+z^2)}{(1-z)^2}.$$ This is separable, but rather different from what you had, so the solution is going to look very different.

I leave the rest for you to solve.

EDIT: I will actually walk through the full problem now. I do not feel as though I am giving you the answer, since you clearly have put work into this. Walking through the full problem will help you see better every potential mistake.

When you solve differential equations, you typically want to avoid doing substitutions that involve the variable of the unknown function, and instead only do substitutions for the function itself. In this case, doing the substitution $v=x+1$ leads to the wrong result, as you will see later during the verification section of my answer. Thus, the verification is needed to calibrate the correct by undoing the shift that occurs due to this substitution. In fact, I believe a better approach would have been to substitute $z=\frac{y}{x+1}$ directly, which would have avoided the need for the verification.

Once you have $$z'v=\frac{-z(1+z^2)}{(1-z)^2},$$ there are two cases to consider. One case is when $z=0$. This already is a solution, so we can move on to the second case immediately, where $z\neq0$. Thus one has $$\frac{(1-z)^2}{z(1+z^2)}z'=-\frac{1}{v}.$$ Notice that $$\frac{(1-z)^2}{z(1+z^2)}=\frac{z^2-2z+1}{z(z^2+1)}=\frac{(z^2+1)-2\cdot{z}}{z(z^2+1)}=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{2}{z^2+1}.$$ Thus $$\left(\frac{1}{z}-\frac{2}{z^2+1}\right)z'=\frac{1}{v}.$$ Here, we need to be very careful. Because of the non-removable singularities at $z=0$ and $v=0$, we have four cases to consider: $z\lt0,v\lt0$; $z\lt0,v\gt0$; $z\gt0,v\lt0$; $z\gt0,v\gt0$. These four cases give, respectively, $$\ln(-z)-2\arctan(z)=-\ln(-v)+A,$$ $$\ln(-z)-2\arctan(z)=-\ln(v)+B,$$ $$\ln(z)-2\arctan(z)=-\ln(-v)+C,$$ $$\ln(z)-2\arctan(z)=-\ln(v)+D.$$ Exponentiating every equation gives $$-z\exp(-2\arctan(z))=A'\frac{1}{-v},$$ $$-z\exp(-2\arctan(z))=B'\frac{1}{v},$$ $$z\exp(-2\arctan(z))=C'\frac{1}{-v},$$ $$z\exp(-2\arctan(z))=D'\frac{1}{v}$$ with $A',B',C',D'\gt0$. The cases can be consolidated to simplify this into the complete piecewise result $$z\exp(-2\arctan(z))=\frac{\alpha}{-v}$$ if $v\lt0$ and $$z\exp(-2\arctan(z))=\frac{\beta}{v}$$ if $v\gt0$.

Unfortunately, I do not believe it is possible to solve for $z$ explicitly in closed-form, because I think there is no closed-form expression for the inverse function of $f$ defined by $f(z)=z\exp(-2\arctan(z))$ on $\mathbb{R}$. But in any case, $$z(v)=\begin{cases} f^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{v}\right)&v\lt0\\f^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{v}\right)&v\gt0\end{cases}$$ Since $z=\frac{y}{v}$, we have that $$y(v)=\begin{cases} vf^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{v}\right)&v\lt0\\vf^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{v}\right)&v\gt0\end{cases}$$ To verify, now consider taking the derivative. For example, just focus on $v\gt0$, for simplicity's sake. Since $f'(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z}-f(z)\frac{2}{z^2+1}$, $$y'(v)=f^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{v}\right)+v{1\over f'\left(f^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{v}\right)\right)}\cdot-\frac{b}{v^2}=\frac{y(v)}{v}-\frac{b}{v\left(\frac{f(f^{-1}(\frac{b}{v}))}{f^{-1}(\frac{b}{v})}-\frac{2f(f^{-1}(\frac{b}{v}))}{f^{-1}(\frac{b}{v})^2+1}\right)}=\frac{y(v)}{v}-\frac{b}{v\left(\frac{\frac{b}{v}}{f^{-1}(\frac{b}{v})}-\frac{2\frac{b}{v}}{f^{-1}(\frac{b}{v})^2+1}\right)}=\frac{y(v)}{v}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{f^{-1}(\frac{b}{v})}-\frac{2}{f^{-1}(\frac{b}{v})^2+1}}=\frac{y(v)}{v}-\frac{1}{\frac{v}{vf^{-1}(\frac{b}{v})}-\frac{2v^2}{(vf^{-1}(\frac{b}{v}))^2+v^2}}=\frac{y(v)}{v}-\frac{1}{\frac{v}{y(v)}-\frac{2v^2}{y(v)^2+v^2}}=\frac{y(v)}{v}-\frac{1}{\frac{v(y(v)^2+v^2)}{y(v)(y(v)^2+v^2)}-\frac{2v^2y(v)}{y(v)(y(v)^2+v^2)}}=\frac{y(v)}{v}-\frac{y(v)(y(v)^2+v^2)}{vy(v)^2+v^3-2v^2y(v)}=\frac{vy(v)(y(v)^2+v^2)-2v^2y(v)^2}{v^2y(v)^2+v^4-2v^3y(v)}-\frac{vy(v)(y(v)^2+v^2)}{v^2y(v)^2+v^4-2v^3y(v)}=\frac{-2v^2y(v)^2}{v^2(v^2+y(v)^2-2vy(v))}=\frac{-2y(v)^2}{v^2+y(v)^2-2vy(v)}=\frac{2y(v)^2}{(v-y(v))^2}.$$ This verification assures that $$y(x)=\begin{cases} (x+1)f^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{x+1}\right)&x\lt{-1}\\(x+1)f^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{(x+1)}\right)&x\gt{-1}\end{cases}$$ for arbitrary real $a,b$ solves the original differential equation everywhere in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\}$. However, notice that if we had directly substituted $v=x+1$ into the solution we obtained prior to verification, we actually would have obtained shifted version of this solution, thus not the correct answer.

As for what Wolfram Alpha gave you, let us go back to $\ln((-1)^mz)-2\arctan(z)=-\ln((-1)^n(x+1))+A_{m,n}$. If you add $-\ln((-1)^n(x+1))$ to both sides of the equation, you get $\ln((-1)^{m+n}y)-2\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x+1}\right)=A_{m,n}$. Multiply by $-1$ on both sides to get $2\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x+1}\right)-\ln((-1)^{m+n}y)=-A_{m,n}$, which is what you obtained if you let $-A_{m,n}=C_{m,n}$. Now, $\arctan\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)=\operatorname{sgn}(t)\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(t)$, so $(-1)^{m+n}\pi-2\arctan\left(\frac{x+1}{y}\right)-\ln((-1)^{m+n}(x+1))=-A_{m,n}$, indicating that $-2\arctan\left(\frac{x+1}{y}\right)-\ln((-1)^{m+n}(x+1))=(-1)^{m+n-1}\pi-A{m,n}$, which is equivalent to $2\arctan\left(\frac{x+1}{y}\right)+\ln((-1)^{m+n}(x+1))=(-1)^{m+n}\pi+A_{m,n}$. As such, your solution and Wolfram Alpha's solution are equivalent, but there were some subtle technical details that needed to be taken care of.

Comment: So I fixed my mistake and now I get $2tan^{-1}{\frac{y}{x+1}}-ln{y}=C$ while on wolfarmalpha I get $ln{y}+2tan^{-1}{\frac{x+1}{y}}=C$ any idea where something might have flipped?

Comment: @CforLinux I edited my answer and expanded rather heavily on the solution, just to cover some technical details and be able to explain every possible doubt I can imagine you may have.

Comment: @Angel wouldn't the last definition for $y(x)$ actually be one for $x \neq -1$ i.e $y(x) = (x+1)f^{-1}(\frac{c}{x+1})\space    x \neq -1$? Also there is the $y\equiv 0$ solution for every $x \neq -1$

Comment: actually I find that this solution is correct as long as $y(x) \neq 0$ and $y \equiv 0$ is a singular solution as long as $x \neq -1$

Comment: @CforLinux *wouldn't the last definition for $y(x)$ actually be one for $x≠−1$ i.e $y(x)=(x+1)f^{−1}(\frac{c}{x+1}), x≠−1$?* No. You are assuming the antidifferentiation constant must be the same at both sides of the singularity, but this is not the case. If you have a different constant on both sides of the singularity, the resulting piecewise function still satisfies the differential equation, as demonstrating in my verification. Thus, those piecewise functions need to be included in the solution. So my solution is correct.

Comment: @CforLinux Also, notice that the solutions of the differential equation only solve the equation on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\}$, not on $\mathbb{R}$, and thus, $y\equiv0$ is included in my solution, with $a=b=0$. Now, $y\equiv0$ can be differentiably extended to $\mathbb{R}$, and it is the only solution with this property, but this is completely irrelevant to the question at hand.